# Android development (thunkable)

Tags: android, thunkable

I am creating an app which has a flask api which contains the symbol prices.

I want the user to enter the symbol and press the submit button and a label will appear that the price of the symbol is:

What will my block code look like?

I have already created the button etc I just want the block code for thunkable

And also I have provided with the web api url.

I tried but not working I can't get the logic right

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.